# Why Can't I get my google maps to update lat/lng on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to get my center location to change on my google map based on a button click.  I have more functionality to add later, but I can't get this basic update to work.  I have a default value that loads on page load.  The button should set a new location, but I see that it does update but then is quickly overridden by the default value because the page loads again.

I am new to google maps, and I am just trying to figure out how to load and interact with the map correctly.

Here is my code:

```
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>                                                        
<script>

    var deanLat = 43.0843816;
    var deanLong = -89.5302394;
    var deanAddress = '1277 deming way, madison wi';

    var stmaryLat = 43.0592730;
    var stmaryLong = -89.4015130;
    var stmaryAddress = '700 S Park St, Madison, WI 53715';

    $("#FindDean").click(function() {
       refreshMap(deanLat, deanLong);
       });

    function alertme(message) {
          alert (message);
      }


    function refreshMap(ilat,ilong) {
       ilat = typeof ilat !== 'undefined' ? ilat : stmaryLat;
       ilong = typeof ilong !== 'undefined' ? ilong : stmaryLong;
        alertme(ilat);
        var mapOptions = {  
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(ilat, ilong)
            };

        gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'),
          mapOptions);
    }


    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
          '&signed_in=true&callback=refreshMap';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
   window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905733/google-maps-api-3-get-coordinates-from-right-click

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$(#FindDean)` the DOM has not yet rendered (the onload event hasn't fired), so the element with id="FindDean" can't be found.

Move this:

```
$("#FindDean").click(function() {
   refreshMap(deanLat, deanLong);
});
```

Inside the onload function:

```
function loadScript() {
  $("#FindDean").click(function() {
     refreshMap(deanLat, deanLong);
  });
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
      '&signed_in=true&callback=refreshMap';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9ukwh63/)

Comment: There is a problem, though.  on my machine, it keeps refreshing the page and I don't know why.  I will post my whole page and maybe there is something in here I am missing that is calling for a page refresh.  The full code is here: http://jsbin.com/qalurazoni/1/edit

Comment: I think my issue is that i have the buttons within a form, which is causing a page refresh.  i took the form out and it works fine now :)

Comment: FYI, i changed the code back to my original, and the confusing thing is that the code works either way.  My issue was the fact that I wrapped my buttons in a form.  Thanks!

Comment: You didn't include that (or any of that HTML) in your question, no way we could have known that (although it was a likely guess...)